# is my data compressed?

Tags: oracle, compression

Lets say I want to implement basic compression for my table. I know it can be done in two steps, for example:

1. alter table MYTABLE compress;
2. alter table MYTABLE move;

Is there a way to check that both steps were implemented? How do I know that data was compressed?

I'm using Oracle 19c if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SQL> create table t1 as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> select dbms_compression.get_compression_type(user, 'T1', rowid) as compression_type,
     count(*)
     from t1 group by dbms_compression.get_compression_type(user, 'T1', rowid);

COMPRESSION_TYPE   COUNT(*)
---------------- ----------
               1      23861

SQL> alter table t1 compress;

Table altered.

SQL> select dbms_compression.get_compression_type(user, 'T1', rowid) as compression_type,
     count(*)
     from t1 group by dbms_compression.get_compression_type(user, 'T1', rowid);

COMPRESSION_TYPE   COUNT(*)
---------------- ----------
               1      23861
```

Finally:

```
SQL> alter table t1 move;

Table altered.

SQL> select dbms_compression.get_compression_type(user, 'T1', rowid) as compression_type,
     count(*)
     from t1 group by dbms_compression.get_compression_type(user, 'T1', rowid);

COMPRESSION_TYPE   COUNT(*)
---------------- ----------
            4096      23861
```

[Table 38-1 DBMS_COMPRESSION Constants - Compression Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_COMPRESSION.html#GUID-8C9942CA-4EBD-48FF-9E8C-A59BF21A0176__BEIBFCCB)

```
1 - No compression
...
4096 - Basic table compression
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run the [`DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_compress.htm#ARPLS65609) system stored procedure to obtain the actual compression ratio for the table. It won't tell you whether someone has run `alter table ... move`, obviously, but it will tell you if the table is actually compressed or only configured.